# How to scroll down and up using splinter in python.

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, web-scraping, splinter

Not able to find command for scrolling using splinter. Wherever I have searched, can find only for selenium but not splinter.

Answer (score 9):

You can scroll with standard javascript by using the Splinter method `execute_script`

**Scroll To Top**

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
```

**Scroll To Bottom**

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior answer is close but not correct

**Scroll to bottom is:**

```
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tarun's answer,

If you would want to go midpage,

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(200, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

maybe you want to go further down the page just increase the number

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(400, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 0):

Splinter also conveniently supports [`scroll_to()`](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L974) on a `WebDriverElement` to scroll it into view.

Example usage: `browser.find_by_css("div.class").scroll_to()`.